# align equal column without using table

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have li like this

```
    <li>0 - 10 Years old</li>
    <li>11 - 20 Years old</li>
```

They have different lengths. I want to center 2 column each row and align them left. But my attempt is not perfect, due to different length they aren't align left equally.

I thought of using table but what's a modern solution? Note that I didn't use any css framework for this.

https://jsfiddle.net/coeh77Lp/

Comment: Can you please add your code to the question instead of just linking to a fiddle - or better still, create a code snippet

Comment: Your code is wrong. First of all you cannot define div outside li in the unordered list. You can simply  width to li 50% and make it display inline block.

Comment: Why not ``display: table`` and ``display: table-row`` in your CSS? It's all the good of tables with none of the cluttered markup.

Comment: You code has syntax error. The only element allowed as a child to an `ul` is a `li`

Answer (score 1):

Just update CSS in your fiddle to 
https://jsfiddle.net/coeh77Lp/3/

```
ul {
  width: 400px;
  column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Yes it's a bit new "CSS3"
Now it's supported by all modern browsers "IE 11"
Check browser support here
http://www.caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn

Also you can use flex box to do this
ul {
  width: 400px;
display:flex;
flex-flow:row wrap;
}
li {flex: 1 1 100%;max-width:50%;}

and if you need to support old browser 
you can use the floating way
li {float:left; width:50%;display:block}

Comment: @JessieAnderson No, CSS Column is not new though haven't had decent browser support until IE10. It is also very buggy, so I recommend to test it thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a fixed width for the `li`:

https://jsfiddle.net/w25m1a81/1/

Comment: how bout responsive? can all the li be at the center?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. But you can center the `ul` which is the parent element of those `li`s, and also give that a fixed width (and a different width in a media query for smaller screens) https://jsfiddle.net/w25m1a81/2/

Answer (score 0):

You could set the float property of each selected `<li>` as left or right.
Also remember to specify `nth-child(2n-1)` property to give a table like alignment.

```
.li{
 float: left;
}
li:nth-child(2n){
float right
}
```

also display: inline-block can be use:

```
.li{
display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 75px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Also providing fixed width, height and margin for the container will improve the alignment

Answer (score 0):

There are some adjustments we should go through so you understand how to achieve the solution you want:

- Avoid inline css styles like on the `<ul>`
- Mixing list markup with a lot of other elements can create chaotic code very fast, lets rename all `<li>` to `<div>`.
- Next we want to wrap all the numeric vales in a container too, because then we have more control over the layout: e.g. `<span class="numerics">51 - 60</span>`
- Now we build up our flexible grid system. We can use the `.customLegend` containers for this but I would recommend to add a new class for `columns` so you can separate your individual styles from those for the layout. https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-css-grid-systems/

I added some styles for free, you can go though the css. I created a jsfiddle too if you want to try further adjustments on your own: https://jsfiddle.net/coeh77Lp/2/

```css
.customLegend {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 170px; /* stack up cols if there is enough space */
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.customLegend .symbol {
  background: #333333;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-right: 3px;
}

.numerics {
  text-align: right; /* better readability */
  min-width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px 4px 2px 2px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
}

.customLegend .label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="customLegend">
  <span class="symbol" style="background: rgb(51, 51, 51);"></span>
  <div class="label"><span class="numerics">0 - 10</span> Years old</div>
</div>
<div class="customLegend">
  <span class="symbol" style="background: rgb(102, 102, 102);"></span>
  <div class="label"><span class="numerics">11 - 20</span> Years old</div>
</div>
<div class="customLegend">
  <span class="symbol" style="background: rgb(153, 153, 153);"></span>
  <div class="label"><span class="numerics">21 - 30</span> Years old</div>
</div>
<div class="customLegend">
  <span class="symbol" style="background: rgb(221, 221, 221);"></span>
  <div class="label"><span class="numerics">31 - 40</span> Years old</div>
</div>
<div class="customLegend">
  <span class="symbol" style="background: rgb(238, 238, 238);"></span>
  <div class="label"><span class="numerics">41 - 50</span> Years old</div>
</div>
<div class="customLegend">
  <span class="symbol" style="background: red;"></span>
  <div class="label"><span class="numerics">51 - 60</span> Years old</div>
</div>
<div class="customLegend">
  <span class="symbol" style="background: blue;"></span>
  <div class="label"><span class="numerics">61 - 70</span> Years old</div>
</div>
<div class="customLegend">
  <span class="symbol" style="background: pink;"></span>
  <div class="label"><span class="numerics">71 - 80</span> Years old</div>
</div>
<div class="customLegend">
  <span class="symbol" style="background: green;"></span>
  <div class="label"><span class="numerics">81 - 0</span> Years old</div>
</div>
```